# Where is the data format for Google's Product search data feeds specified?

Tags: google-workspace

Where is the specification for the file format for building data feeds to populate Google's Product Search (neé Froogle)?

When I follow the links from product search, it guides me through setting up a merchant account (fair enough), and then asks me to specify the filename, but it does not tell me what format that file should be in, or ask for any location information as to where to retrieve it from?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a link to the overview:
http://www.google.com/support/merchants/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=188478

Here is a link to the specific xml you need:
http://www.google.com/support/merchants/bin/answer.py?answer=188494

Here is some sample XML that Google hands out:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<feed xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom" xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0">
    <title>The name of your data feed.</title>
    <link rel="self" href="http://www.example.com"/>
    <updated>2006-06-11T18:30:02Z</updated>
    <author>
        <name>The name of the author.</name>
    </author>
    <id>tag:example.com,2006-06-11:/support/products</id>
<entry>
<title>Red wool sweater</title>
<g:brand>Acme</g:brand>
<g:condition>new</g:condition>
<summary>Comfortable and soft, this sweater will keep you warm on those cold winter nights.</summary>
<id>1</id>
<g:image_link>http://www.example.com/image1.jpg</g:image_link>
<link href="http://www.example.com/item1-info-page.html"/>
<g:mpn>ABC123</g:mpn>
<g:price>25</g:price>
<g:product_type>Clothing &amp; Accessories &gt; Clothing &gt; Outerwear &gt; Sweaters</g:product_type>
<g:quantity>3</g:quantity>
<g:shipping>
   <g:country>US</g:country>
   <g:region>MA</g:region>
   <g:service>Ground</g:service>
   <g:price>5.95</g:price>
</g:shipping>
<g:shipping>
   <g:country>US</g:country>
   <g:region>024*</g:region>
   <g:service>Ground</g:service>
   <g:price>7.95</g:price>
</g:shipping>
<g:tax>
   <g:country>US</g:country>
   <g:region>CA</g:region>
   <g:rate>8.25</g:rate>
   <g:tax_ship>y</g:tax_ship>
</g:tax>
<g:tax>
   <g:country>US</g:country>
   <g:region>926*</g:region>
   <g:rate>8.75</g:rate>
   <g:tax_ship>y</g:tax_ship>
</g:tax>
<g:upc>0001230001232</g:upc>
<g:weight>0.1 lb</g:weight>
</entry>
</feed>
```